# jquery post request not send in mobile view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I m using following jquery code

```
var ajax_url = "tmp/ajax.php";
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="radio_view"]', function () {
    var view_array = {};
    view_array.session_id = $(this).attr('data-session_id');
    view_array.buyer_id = $(this).attr('data-buyer_id');
    view_array.lot_id = $(this).attr('data-lot_id');
    view_array.view = $(this).val();
    $.post(ajax_url, {act: 'save_view', view_array: view_array});
});
```

On full view in pc it is working fine the request will be sent to tmp/ajax.php but on mobile view the request not send in Network it is showing no request captured.

Comment: Do you use different domain/subdomain on mobile view maybe?

Comment: no it is same for any device

Comment: Check if click event is triggered by inserting `alert`, `console.log` or adding breakpoint inside callback. If it is, then you now it's something else.

Comment: In mobile view now after clicking 6-7 times the request will be sent :(

Comment: on mobile it is working by double click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using radio(As I am guessing by name attribute) button to trigger ajax call , mostly 'click' does not work in non-ie browser. Try changing from 'click' to 'change' event.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="radio_view"]', function () {
//rest of the code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var ajax_url = "tmp/ajax.php";
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="radio_view"]', function () {
var view_array = {};
view_array.session_id = $(this).attr('data-session_id');
view_array.buyer_id = $(this).attr('data-buyer_id');
view_array.lot_id = $(this).attr('data-lot_id');
view_array.view = $(this).val();
$.post(ajax_url, {act: 'save_view', view_array: view_array});

});
```